Whatsapp flows API is mixing data from different users
I have a flow developed with 7 screens, simulating the request for an airline ticket.
On the second screen the user selects the city of origin and on the third screen the city of destination. My flow is initializing and finishing normally until the last step, but I have a data loading problem and a user is in another user's flow.
Example: if user A has already finished the flow or is on the fourth or fifth screen... the data from the previous ones is being loaded into user B's flow, even though the flow token is different, it is storing a kind of cache between different users.
    {
        "recipient_type": "individual",
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "type": "interactive",
        "interactive": {
            "type": "flow",
            "header": {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Viagem corporativa"
            },
            "body": {
                "text": "Preencha o formulário"
            },
            "action": {
                "name": "flow",
                "parameters": {
                    "mode": "draft",
                    "flow_message_version": "3",
                    "flow_token": JSON.stringify(obj), 
                                         // each user have one "obj"
                    "flow_id": "733XXXXXXX",
                    "flow_cta": "Responder",
                    "flow_action": "data_exchange"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

I've already tried using version 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 of WhatsApp flows.
And I see that the flow token is unique for each call to the WhatsApp API
